# Is there a way to silently install and run combofix?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

Does anybody know a way to run combofix without all the dialog boxes? I've tried guessing at a few switches, /s /silent etc, but none of them work, and I can't find any info googling it.

Let me know if you know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Combofix doesn't need to be installed; you just run it. But I don't think you can run it silently since the program comes with a disclaimer that it should *"never be used in an unsupervised environment."*

Comment: I mean, thats all fine and good, but I own a computer repair shop and we run it on about 250 computers a month without problems, so I'm not worried about using it in an unsupervised environment =)

I will just write an AutoIT script to do it I think...

Comment: It would be nice, but combofix was originally designed for people helping noobs in forums to clean their PCs, great Idea for experienced users though, just scan and spit out the log file.